# .htaccess how to create an URLs like http://example.com/~someuser

Tags: .htaccess

How do I can create and process an URLs like this via .htaccess rules: http://example.com/~someuser

And then get a parameter "username" as a part of $_GET array. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^~([^/]+)/?$ /script.php?user=$1 [L]
```

If those rules are placed in the htaccess file in your document root, then it'll capture the "someuser" part of the URL and rewrite it to the `script.php` script and set it as the `$_GET['user']` variable. You can replace `script.php` with whatever name of the script you want the variable to go to.